# .htaccess: How to define Rewrite Rule depending on HTTP status code

Tags: .htaccess

I want to define a .htaccess rewrite condition that allows me to define a rewrite rule depending on HTTP status code. With PHP there is no problem, but in .htaccess I found no solution in any Apache documentation.

Comment: What status codes exactly, and "coming" from where? Rewriting happens at the beginning of the request processing, so if we are talking about any status code set by a script or something, that won't really work. You could at most set up some sort of proxy rule, I suppose, so that your webserver itself makes the request that will somehow get answered with a specific status code, and then decides what to do with that, before it passes it on to the client.

Comment: It's about status codes 30x, 4x and 50x and if they are set by any application. Best example is 404 or 301, 302.

Comment: The background of my question is that I am using a webserver based HTTP cache that also caches requests to e.a. URLs that don't exist or are redirected. With rewrite rules I can either set no-cache or can purge the cache by rewrite rules, but I need the status code to define such rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's about status codes 30x, 4x and 50x and if they are **set by any application.**

That's simply not possible with `.htaccess`.

By the time the application is sending back the response, mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule` / "rewrite condition") has long since finished processing the request.

You can only check the HTTP *request*, not the *response* with mod_rewrite.